# Azure Log Analytics POST / Search Query in Plain HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, powershell, azure

I want to Upload an event to Azure LOG Analytics and Retrieve an event using plain JavaScript with XMLHTTPRequest or JQuery rest .
1.**Using powershell invoke-webrequest, i am  able to Upload the event but not through the below request from html**
2. **Need help in retrieving an event from Azure Log Analytics RestApi**

for the first one Here is the sample code **HTTP405: BAD METHOD - The HTTP verb used is not supported.**

```
     var strBody = {         
 "Hostname": "sdfsfsdf",
      "Customer": "sdfsfdsfdsf",
      "RoundTripLatencyInMs": 67,

  };
  debugger;
  customerId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  sharedkey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  logType = "xxxxxxxxx";
  TimeStampField = "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ";
//  encodebody = stringToUtf16ByteArray(JSON.stringify(strBody).toString('utf8'));//encode_utf8(JSON.stringify(strBody));

  str = strBody;
  var byteArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
      if (str.charCodeAt(i) <= 0x7F)
          byteArray.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
      else {
          var h = encodeURIComponent(str.charAt(i)).substr(1).split('%');
          for (var j = 0; j < h.length; j++)
              byteArray.push(parseInt(h[j], 16));
      }
 // return byteArray;
  encodebody = byteArray;
  method = 'POST';
  resource = '/api/logs';
  //contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  var d =new Date();

  msdate = d.toUTCString(); //'Thu, 14 Jul 2017 06:35:52 GMT';
  contentLength = encodebody.length;

  //Signature
  xHeaders = "x-ms-date:" + msdate;
  stringToHash = method + "\n" + contentLength + "\n" + xHeaders + "\n" + resource;
  //message=stringToHash;
  var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToHash, sharedkey);
  var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
 // document.write(hashInBase64);
  //authorization = 'SharedKey ' + customerId +':'+ hashInBase64 ;

  signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToHash), CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(sharedkey)));
  authorization = 'SharedKey ' + customerId + ':' + signature;

  uri = "https://" + customerId + ".ods.opinsights.azure.com" + resource + "?api-version=2016-04-01";

  var myHttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  debugger;
  $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (data) {
          //do something to data
      },
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "SharedKey " + customerId + ":" + signature);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-date', msdate);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', '2014-02-14');
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8');
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          //xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=nometadata');
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Log-Type", logType);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("time-generated-field", TimeStampField);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
          //xhr.setRequestHeader('DataServiceVersion', '3.0;NetFx');
          //xhr.setRequestHeader('MaxDataServiceVersion', '3.0;NetFx');
      },
      datatype:'json',
      //contentType: 'application/json',
      data:encodebody,
      error: function (rcvData) {
          console.log("ERRor");
          console.log(rcvData);
      }
  });
```

Any pointers will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

As you made a REST call from browser side using javascript, the browser would first send an HTTP request by the `OPTIONS` method to the resource to look for CORS headers. See [Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). And Log Analytics REST API doesn't allow the `OPTIONS` HTTP verb. It means that the API doesn't support CORS. So, it raises your issue.

[image]

So, you should call the REST API by using server side language like PHP, Python, Node.js, etc.